# error: bad character in group name '(normal_date)' at position 4

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to use regular expression to find date in dd/mm/yyyy format.This is the expression i used.

```
normal_date=r'(?P<(normal_date)>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})'
```

But i am getting an error: bad character in group name '(normal_date)' at position 4.I checked the similar threads but unable to find an answer.I am using python.please help..!

Comment: You don't need parens in the group name, just `r'(?P<normal_date> ...`.

Comment: Thanks,I was unable to find this for an hour